# How to hide all columns after eleventh column

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, row, cells

I have a gridview that displays some information about jobs for companies. The columns at the end are displaying different piece types so these number of columns can change if pieces are removed or added. 
Since I don't know how many columns could be there I can't use `row.Cells[8].Visible = false;`because I don't know the number. 
The user can decide if they want to see these pieces in the report. So if a radio button is clicked I need all the columns after the eleventh column (this is where the piece columns start) to be hidden.

```
protected void gvResults_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (TableRow row in gvResults.Controls[0].Controls)
        {
            if (rbDailyReport.Checked)
            {
                row.Cells[0].Visible = true;
                row.Cells[8].Visible = false;
            }

        }

    }
```

If code works if I know the number of the column to hide. So I need to check if the row is greater than 11 then hide all rows.

Comment: Using a for loop starting at index 10 would be my first thought

Comment: @joko could you show the code for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this?

```
protected void gvResults_RowCreated(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    for (int i = 8; i < e.Row.Cells.Count; i++)
    {
        e.Row.Cells[i].Visible = false;
    }
}
```

Start from index `8` and hide all the columns whose index is greater than 8.

Comment: That works for hiding all the rows but the column headers are still displaying. How do I hide them to?

Comment: @user123456789 - No it should hide the column as well. You doing this inside `gvResults_RowCreated` event only right? You have _autogenerate_ columns **true** or **false**?